# Excluding ID field when fitting model in R

Tags: r, random-forest, data-science

I have a simple Random Forest model I have created and tested in R. For now I have excluded an internal company ID from my training/testing data frames. Is there a way in R that I could include this column in my data and have the training/execution of my model ignore the field?

I obviously would not want the model to try and incorporate it as a variable, but upon an export of the data with a column added of the predicted outcome, I would need that internal id to tie back in other customer data so I know what customers have been categorized as

I am just using the out of the box random forest function from the randomForest library

```
#divide data into training and test sets
set.seed(3)
id<-sample(2,nrow(Churn_Model_Data_v2),prob=c(0.7,0.3),replace = TRUE)
churn_train<-Churn_Model_Data_v2[id==1,]
churn_test<-Churn_Model_Data_v2[id==2,]

#changes Churn data 1/2 to a factor for model
Churn_Model_Data_v2$`Churn` <- as.factor(Churn_Model_Data_v2$`Churn`)
churn_train$`Churn` <- as.factor(churn_train$`Churn`)
#churn_test$`Churn` <- as.factor(churn_test$`Churn`)

bestmtry <- tuneRF(churn_train,churn_train$`Churn`, stepFactor = 1.2, 
improve =0.01, trace=T, plot=T )

#creates model based on training data, views model
churn_forest <- randomForest(`Churn`~. , data= churn_train )
churn_forest


#shows us what variables are most important
importance(churn_forest)
varImpPlot(churn_forest)

#predicts churn diagnosis on test data
predict_churn <- predict(churn_forest, newdata = churn_test, type="class")
predict_churn
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `randomForest(Churn~.-id, data=churn_train)` ? When using the `~.` syntax you can usually add a minus sign before the single variable (or vector of variables) you want to exclude. As an aside, you also don't need all the quotation marks around `Churn`, those are really only necessary when you have variable names that contain spaces like `Churn Var`

Comment: @GraceMahoney thanks so much for the tip. I appreciate the help on what probably was a pretty dumb question from someone somewhat new to R. I often find that its something very simple in the syntax that allows me to do something that I imagine would be very complicated. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example of excluding a particular column or set of columns is as follows

```
library(MASS)
temp<-petrol
randomForest(No ~ .,data = temp[, !(colnames(temp) %in% c("SG"))]) # One Way
randomForest(No ~ .-SG,data = temp) #Another way with similar result
```

This method of exclusion is commonly valid across other fuctions/alogorithms in R too.